# Ввод байтовой строки от пользователя

Tags: python, строки, byte

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при вводе байтовой строки:

```
a = input() #b'YW\x94/{X\xce\xb9'
type(a) #<class 'str'>
```

Что нужно сделать с переменной "a" или с вводом, чтобы получить байтовую строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это?:

```
import ast
a = input() #b'YW\x94/{X\xce\xb9'
b = ast.literal_eval(a)
print(type(b))
print(b)

#<class 'bytes'>
#b'YW\x94/{X\xce\xb9'
```